# Windows 7 boot from downloaded .iso

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

Downloaded Windows 7 .iso off the net and want to install from USB key on old laptop (previously/still running XP) that has no CD/DVD drive.  Here's what I've got so far:

- Read the instructions in this post: http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=345 , which were quite straight forward and clear.
- Properly formatted USB key with another laptop (this one running vista), also with no DVD drive
- wasn't sure how to make the USB bootable, since my .iso was downloaded and I have no DVD drive.

Any help would be *much* appreciated!!

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft has released a tool to create a bootable Windows 7 installation flash drive:

[Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3010-18513_4-11115251.html?tag=mncol) ,

And Here the [instructions](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/10/26/windows-7-usbdvd-download-tool-creates-and-makes-bootable-dvd-disc-or-usb-flashhard-drive-from-iso-image/) from *MyDigitalLife*.

Answer (score 4):

You should follow the tutorial from Microsoft titled [Use a USB Key to Install Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd535816.aspx).  The basic process (as outlined in that article) is as follows:

1. Launch DISKPART from the command prompt (or by going to Start->Run).
2. Select your flash drive (to list all disks, type `list disk`, and then `select disk X` where `x` is the proper drive number).
3. Clean the disk using the `clean` command.  **This will wipe all data on the drive.**
4. Now, run `create partition primary`, and then run `active`.
5. Finally, you can format it with the `format fs=fat32 quick` command, and then assign it a drive letter with the `assign` command.

Now, you should be able to just copy everything from the Windows 7 ISO/disc into the root of the flash drive, and boot the system from the drive.

Comment: diskpart doesn't list my usb key in the list because i'm running Windows XP on this machine. I can do list volume and see it as volume 4 though.

Comment: Running XP shouldn't cause diskpart to not list your disk. . . But if you can select the volume, that is good.

Comment: @surfasb: Could it be that, due to the nature of the USB Flash disk, it may not be listed?

Comment: @Gunner: No idea.  I've never seen anything like that and previously thought something like that would be impossible.  You sure the disk isn't listed?

Comment: @surfasb: I am pretty sure it wasn't listed on my XP machine. Then I moved it to a Win 7 PC and formatted that using NTFS. It was visible in that machine and I was able to carry out the instructions above.

Comment: How big is the flash drive? Note XP needs an update to see flash drives over a certain size.

Answer (score 3):

use **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** to prepare your USB stick, it doesn't get any easier.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have a DVD drive to use bootsect, but there is a copy of bootsect in that Windows 7 ISO. Open it with a regular compression utility such as [7-zip](http://7-zip.org) and extract bootsect.exe which is under the **boot** directory. You can then follow the rest of the steps in your guide, just make sure your current directory in command prompt is the one with bootsect.exe in it while you execute the commands.