# Creating a Windows 7 bootable flash drive from a Windows XP machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 boot from downloaded .iso](https://superuser.com/questions/76759/windows-7-boot-from-downloaded-iso)

I have a Windows 7 CD that I copied the contents to my Flash drive, unfortunately it doesn't boot up.

I tried looking up various online tutorials and downloaded tools like the HP Utility Disk and BartPE and etc. I can't seem to get anything working here.

I figured maybe I'd just copy the boot.ini, ntldr and ntdetect files from my C drive onto the flash, but I'm not sure what the boot.ini file should have to boot the Windows 7 install.

The Windows 7 setup.exe is on the root of the flash drive. Anyone know what I should do here?